# Outputting Polish characters in XML

Tags: php, xml

I am outputting some Polish addresses in xml from PHP but Firefox says this xml is not well formed because of the characters like ó in the address. How do I output Polish characters like this and have valid xml. I am using this header in PHP:

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
```

Do I need to set some sort of character set?

This is the error message firefox gives:

XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: Poland.php
Line Number 1, Column 635:

This is the xml:

```
<data><stores><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>59</storeCode><address>Bialystok: ul. Narodowych Sil Zbrojnych 13</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>42</storeCode><address>Bielsko-Biala: ul. Warszawska 186</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>27</storeCode><address>Bydgoszcz: ul. Szubinska 5</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>43</storeCode><address>Bytom: Aleja Jana Nowaka-Jezioranskiego 27</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>45</storeCode><address>Chorzw: ul. Sportowa 31</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>47</storeCode><address>Cieszyn: ul. Liburnia 10</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>48</storeCode><address>Czestochowa: ul. Jana Pawla II 2</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>30</storeCode><address>Elk: ul. Ciepla 2</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>9</storeCode><address>Gdansk: ul. Odyseusza 2</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>8</storeCode><address>Gdansk Oliwa: Al. Grunwaldzka 262</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>72</storeCode><address>Gliwice: Pszczynska 315</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>12</storeCode><address>Glog�w: ul. Ks. J. Poniatowskiego 10</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>5</storeCode><address>Gniezno: ul. Palucka 1</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>15</storeCode><address>Gorz�w Wielkopolski: ul. Czartoryskiego 1</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>14</storeCode><address>Jelenia G�ra: Al. Jana Pawla II 11</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>6</storeCode><address>Kalisz: ul. Tylna 17-23</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>50</storeCode><address>Katowice: ul. Rozdzienskiego 198</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>19</storeCode><address>Kedzierzyn Kozle: Al. Armii Krajowej 40</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>24</storeCode><address>Kielce: ul. Wrzosowa 42</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>28</storeCode><address>Koszalin: ul. Paderewskiego 2</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>35</storeCode><address>Krak�w: ul. Sosnowiecka 147</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>36</storeCode><address>Krak�w: ul. Pilot�w 6</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>37</storeCode><address>Krak�w: ul. Walerego Slawka 1</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>39</storeCode><address>Krak�w: ul. Zakopianska 62</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>16</storeCode><address>Legnica: ul. Roberta Schumana 9</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>18</storeCode><address>Lubin: Al. Komisji Edukacji Narodowej 1</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>71</storeCode><address>Lublin: Melgiewska 16 c</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>44</storeCode><address>L�dz: ul. Wr�blewskiego 31</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>46</storeCode><address>L�dz: ul. Wydawnicza 13</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>49</storeCode><address>L�dz: ul. Sikorskiego 2/6</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>38</storeCode><address>Minsk Mazowiecki: Stojadla, ul. Warszawska 63b</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>40</storeCode><address>Nowy Targ: ul. Szaflarska 176</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>58</storeCode><address>Nysa: ul. Zygmunta Krasinskiego 31</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>22</storeCode><address>Opole: ul. Wiejska 141a</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>26</storeCode><address>Ostrowiec Swietokrzyski: ul. Stefana Zeromskiego 13</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>64</storeCode><address>Oswiecim: ul. Zatorska 1</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>4</storeCode><address>Poznan: ul. Murawa 39</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>62</storeCode><address>Poznan: ul. Grecka 30A</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>53</storeCode><address>Przemysl: ul. Lwowska 17</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>52</storeCode><address>Racibrz: ul. Rybnicka 95</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>11</storeCode><address>Rumia: ul. Grunwaldzka 5</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>73</storeCode><address>Rybnik: Obwiednia Plnocna 21</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>55</storeCode><address>Rzeszw: Al. Rejtana 67</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>76</storeCode><address>Skarzysko-Kamienna: Al. Jzefa Pilsudskiego 2</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>51</storeCode><address>Skierniewice: ul. Wyszynskiego 10</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>13</storeCode><address>Slupsk: ul. Hubalczykw 2</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>54</storeCode><address>Sosnowiec: ul. Dlugosza 82</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>7</storeCode><address>Stare Miasto kolo Konina: ul. Ogrodowa 31</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>61</storeCode><address>Stargard Szczecinski: ul. Tadeusza Kosciuszki 73a</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>63</storeCode><address>Swarzedz: Sienkiewicza 23</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>31</storeCode><address>Szczecin: ul. Ku Sloncu 67b</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>33</storeCode><address>Szczecin: ul. Poludniowa 21</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>34</storeCode><address>Szczecin: ul. Wiosenna 80</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>56</storeCode><address>Tarnowskie Gry: ul. Obwodnica 16</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>41</storeCode><address>Tarnw: ul. Nowodabrowska 127</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>29</storeCode><address>Torun: ul. Szosa Bydgoska 102 A</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>20</storeCode><address>Walbrzych: ul. H. Wieniawskiego 21</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>1</storeCode><address>Warszawa: ul. Popularna 71</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>2</storeCode><address>Warszawa: Al. Krakowska 75</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>3</storeCode><address>Warszawa: ul. Glebocka 15a</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>74</storeCode><address>Warszawa: ul. Grochowska 21</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>21</storeCode><address>Wroclaw: ul. Graniczna 2a</address></store><store><storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName><storeCode>23</storeCode><address>Wroclaw: ul. B. Krzywoustego 126a</address></store></stores><feedData><executionTimeInSeconds>0.0006</executionTimeInSeconds><numberOfCastoramaPolandStores>69</numberOfCastoramaPolandStores></feedData></data>
```

Comment: Add a CDATA node around your text node before adding it to address

Comment: @Marvin, no, that's completely wrong advice. CDATA makes no difference at all unless the text contains '&' or '<' characters.

Comment: What's the exact message you're getting from Firefox? That XML *isn't* well-formed, but that's because you've got a spare opening `<store>` at the end. We need to see the whole document, or at least more of it, including knowing which is the root element, plus the XML declaration, and we'll need to know what encoding it's in (That ó character you're using there is UTF-8 as far as we can tell now it's been pasted into Stack Overflow...)

Comment: Hi I changed the question to include the full output xml and the error message from firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the XML fragment won't parse then it's probably because the character encoding is not what the XML parser thinks it is. If there's no XML declaration at the start of the file then Firefox will either assume UTF-8, or it may (I'm not sure) try to use encoding information from the HTTP headers. The best thing is to:

a) make sure the file is encoded in UTF-8

b) make sure it has an XML declaration that says it is encoded in UTF-8

c) make sure it is served with MIME type application/xml (NOT text/xml, which could cause it to be incorrectly transcoded on transmission)

If the existing file is some other encoding, for example ISO 8859-2, then you could try to send it to the browser in that encoding but this relies on browsers supporting the encoding, whereas support for UTF-8 is universal.

Comment: Thanks yes I just need to add a line to say it was encoded in UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

your example is in fact ill-formed: it ends with the opening tag for the `store` element.

```
<store>
 <storeName>Castorama Poland</storeName>
 <storeCode>45</storeCode>
 <address>Chorzów: ul. Sportowa 31</address>
 </store>
<store>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding:

```
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n";
```